# Twitter card is not dispalying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-card

I am getting the card preview but when i post a tweet i am not getting the photo.Cant figure out what is being missing.Any help would be appreciable

application.html

```
<% if content_for?(:head) %>
      <%= yield(:head) %>
<% end %>
```

index.html

```
    <% @feeds.each_with_index do |feed,i| %>
            <div>
              <% content_for :head do %>

                <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
                <meta name="twitter:title" content="<%= feed["title"] %>" />
                <meta name="twitter:description" content="<%= feed["description"] %>" />
                <meta name="twitter:image" content="<%= feed["image"].present? ? feed["image"] : feed["json_data"]["img"] %>" />
                <meta name="twitter:url" content="http://<%= select_url %>/entry/<%= feed["slug"]%>" />

                <meta property="og:url" content="http://<%= select_url %>/entry/<%= feed["slug"]%>" />
                <meta property="og:image" content="<%= feed["image"].present? ? feed["image"] : feed["json_data"]["img"] %>"  />
                <meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
                <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
                <meta property="og:title" content="<%=  feed["title"] %>" />
              <% end %>
            </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `<% content_for :head do %>` block outside the loop i.e. iterate over your `@feeds` variable inside the `content_for` block.

Comment: yes i did but no luck

Comment: OK. Two questions: 1) Is the `@feeds` variable definitely returning something? Drop `<%= @feeds.inspect %>` into your code. 2) What happens if you try without using `content_for`?

Comment: og meta tags are already working.yes @feeds are returning all feeds.The problem happens with twitter cards.Here are the logs of card-validator " 
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  14 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully
 " but when i tweet just link is being posted.

Comment: Here is my updated "Robot.txt" file                       User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /